# Change the main loop Wordpress impact on the server?

Tags: custom-field, loop, pre-get-posts

I used pre_get_posts to change the loop of my Wordpress site. The idea of this loop is not show posts I define an expiration date, whose dates are added in a custom field ( postexpiry ) . These consultations via key (present in my code) require more server work? Does anyone have a better suggestion than that? I feel that the homepage of my website is loading more slowly, since, for example, the category page not.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q ) {

if ( (is_home() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_search()) && $q->is_main_query() && !is_admin() )
{

$q->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );

$date_now = strtotime(current_time( 'mysql' ));
$meta_query = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
    'key'     => 'postexpiry',
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
array(
    'key'     => 'postexpiry',
    'value'   => '0',
    'compare' => '=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'postexpiry',
            'value'   => $date_now,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),

    ),

);

$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

return $q;

}
});
```

Comment: Please first read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), then revisit all your posts and accept the answers that was useful in solving your issue. `pre_get_posts` are the coorect way to alter the main query. Note, complex nested meta queries are much slower, specially on big databases